# launch browser via php code

Tags: php

Is it possible to invoke the browser via php code ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use javscript in php

Comment: @AhmedGinani - You can _echo_ javascript in PHP, but that's not "using" javascript. Sure, you can actually run js through a js engine with PHP but since PHP is on the server, that will have no effect on the client.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ,they don't like me :(

Answer (score 1):

PHP is processed by the Web server.  The browser is a client application on a client machine.  The server cannot launch a client application without having a helper application in place and running on the client machine.  Any other architecture would be ***very bad*** from a security standpoint - the client machine would have ***no control*** over who could run an application on their machine.

Answer (score 0):

if you use firefox, you can use this:

```
pclose(popen('firefox -url http://www.example.com/reader.php?code=12345 &', 'r'));
```

other browsers have different console arguments, so you can try it yourself.

Comment: so I can execute that via php code ?

Comment: Yes, use cli mode. Within a web server environment, unexpected results may happen, and you can not open a browser on the client side.

Comment: what cli mode ?

Comment: use this in command-line interface, like `php openbrowser.php`, not in cgi or fast-cgi. @jemz